# Android - Listener for catching changes in a View's properties (e.g. android:layout_marginTop)

Tags: android, android-layout, listener, android-view, android-event

In Android, can you create a Listener for catching changes in a View's properties (width / height / margin / position relative to top of the screen)?

I want to trigger an event when layout_marginTop="10dp" is changed to a different value.

Comment: You can try "OnLayoutChangeListener" but be careful: it listening almost EVERYTHING and sometimes does it twice :)

And yes, better late than never - so hello from 2021 ;)

Answer (score 25):

What about implementing a OnLayoutChangeListener that gets called when a View is moved due to Layout Change

```
new View().addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft,
                    int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
});
```

Excerpt from Android API:

> Add a
>   listener that will be called when the bounds of the view change due to
>   layout processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to listen to changes of ALL AVAILABLE properties of the View (padding, margin, width, height, rotation, tag, visibility), not just the changes to the left/top/right/bottom properties.

Comment: AFAIK the margin doesn't belong to a View. It can be contained in View.getLayoutParams or only be stored in the Parents View. However: Is it an Option to use derived View Classes and add the Listener you want?

Comment: It is a possibility to use derived View Classes, if the method can be implemented on multiple View Class derivatives (e.g. ImageView, TextView). It is not a problem to create extended View Classes of all the View Class derivatives that need to implement a propertyListener for. For example: If I need 2 views (ImageView + TextView) with  propertyListeners -> I should create 2 custom View Classes that extend ImageView and TextView. These 2 custom Views have propertyListeners set to them.

Comment: It is usable for handling view Y changed in adjustResize for detecting keyboard show/hide events?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to all properties changes directly, the answer is NO.

But maybe you can listen to the `draw` or `preDraw` events provided by `ViewTreeObserver` and check whether the concerned property changed or not when these events happened.

`View` is what you view on screen, so changes of any of its properties should invalidate itself and trigger `draw` or `preDraw` events, right?