# Determine when Android View's position is updated

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem statement where I have to detect changes in Android View's location.

eg. I should get notified when view's location is changed by following API call

```
View.setX() or View.setY()
```

I can extend the View and override above two methods but if View is inside some parent view and if someone calls **`ParentView.setX()`** or **`ParentView.setY()`**, it will still update child view location.

I also tried onDraw method, it gets called only once. Is there any method available which get notified every time View's location state is updated.

Comment: Use OnLayoutChangeListener. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248628/android-listener-for-catching-changes-in-a-views-properties-e-g-androidlay

Comment: Nope, it's not being called, I already have global layout listener on view tree

Comment: call requestlayout() when changing your params

Comment: I don't have control over View's what's being called, my code sits as part of third party library

Answer (score -1):

viewgroup location is determined by his parents,we can change his width and height by viewgroup layoutparams,or implements its onLayout method to change his location.